# Is UCP supported with Websphere liberty

Tags: oracle, websphere-liberty, ucp, open-liberty

I cant seem to find a straight answer on this question. We would like to use Oracle's UCP with liberty base/open. Is this doable? Has anyone tried this and had problems, did it work? Thanks for answering.

Comment: I'm not sure. In Weblogic it is better to use Gridlink, which is kind of superset UCP. It does not work with JBOSS, according to their JIRA they have problems to integrate is with JTA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty nor OpenLiberty currently support use of Oracle UCP.  For the commercial version, there is a [request for enhancement (RFE)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewChangeRequest&CR_ID=88268) for which you can vote, this helps us determine the priority of requests.  For OpenLiberty, you can open an [new function issue](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

As of version 19.0.0.4, Oracle UCP is now supported in both WebSphere Liberty and OpenLiberty.  This [blog post](https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/04/26/reactive-microservices-microprofile-19004.html#oracle) has more information on how to configure a data source with Oracle UCP in OpenLiberty or WebSphere Liberty.